# ArrayList to String with separated by Comma

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` and I want to output completely as a String with separated by `comma`.

My code is

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");

String listString = "";

for (String s : list)
{
    listString += s + ",";
}

System.out.println(listString);
```

But the output is `one,two,three,` and i want `one,two,three` without using `replace method`.

I am using `JAVA`

Comment: `listString += (listString.isEmpty() ? "" : ",") + s;`. Note that you should use a `StringBuilder` rather than direct concatenation.

Comment: @AndyTurner how to use StringBuilder for same?

Comment: String class has a method called join, so that you don't have to iterate through the collection to join the elements. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) is the doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8+ you could use a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) (and you can use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) to initialize your `List`). Something like,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
for (String s : list) {
    sj.add(s);
}
System.out.println(sj.toString());
```

Output is (as requested)

```
one,two,three
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Java 8:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
String joinedString = String.join(",", list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("one");
        list.add("two");
        list.add("three");

        String listString = "";

        for (int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++)
            listString += list.get(i) + ",";

        System.out.println(listString+list.get(list.size()-1));
    }
}
```

Output:

`one,two,three`

http://ideone.com/PkAOOq

Answer (score 0):

Just use `String.substring`. Here you go:

```
listString = listString.substring(0, listString.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.StringJoiner for this, instead of a List:

```
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
    joiner.add("one");
    joiner.add("two"),
    joiner.add("three");

    String listString = joiner.toString();
```

If you are not using Java8, then consider using StringBuilder. Then your final string can be:

```
System.out.println(listString.substring(0, listString.length() - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

For a pre Java 8 solution, since the default `toString()` gives you `[one, two, three]`.

```
String s = list.toString();
s = s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
list.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```